# How to avoid data repetition insertion?

Tags: sql-server, node.js, excel, openrowset, node-mssql

Recently I have posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37109826/error-while-running-node-mssql-query/37110440?noredirect=1#comment61818737_37110440), it contains some syntax error, now the code is running without error, thanks to @Arulkumar.

But now I am facing one more problem, data from excel sheet is storing properly on to SQL Server database, but when I press refresh button or if I go to that link again in my application, data is repeating in the database. Means again it is retrieving values from excel and storing same data again in the database.

How can I avoid data repetition. Can any one please help me to solve this issue? Code and excel sheet sample is there in the above mentioned link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need MERGE statement

```
request.query('MERGE [mytable] as target USING (SELECT SalesPersonID, TerritoryID FROM OPENROWSET('  + 
        '\'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0\', \'Excel 12.0;Database=D:\\sample\\test\\data\\1540_OPENROWSET_Examples.xls;HDR=YES\', ' + 
        '\'SELECT SalesPersonID, TerritoryID FROM [SELECT_Example$]\')' +
        ' ) as source' +
        ' ON target.SalesPersonID = source.SalesPersonID' +
        ' WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET TerritoryID = source.TerritoryID' +
        ' WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (SalesPersonID, TerritoryID) VALUES (source.SalesPersonID, source.TerritoryID);'
        ,function(err,recordset){
    if(err) console.log(err)
```

It will update `TerritoryID` if there is already row with same `SalesPersonID` and insert row if there is no matches in `mytable`.

If you need join on both fields change this:

```
ON target.SalesPersonID = source.SalesPersonID
```

On this:

```
ON target.SalesPersonID = source.SalesPersonID AND target.TerritoryID = source.TerritoryID
```

And after that - remove this string because it doesn't need anymore:

```
'WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET TerritoryID = source.TerritoryID' +
```

Comment: Hi , thank you for replying with line by line explanation , i tried to run code , it is giving some syntax errors :

Comment: `{ [RequestError: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.]
  name: 'RequestError',
  message: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword \'as\'.',
  code: 'EREQUEST',
  number: 156,
  lineNumber: 1,

  class: 15,
  serverName: 'localhost\\SQLEXPRESS',
  procName: '',
  precedingErrors:
   [ { [RequestError: Incorrect syntax near '('.]
       name: 'RequestError',
       message: 'Incorrect syntax near \'(\'.',
       code: 'EREQUEST',
       number: 102,
       lineNumber: 1,
       state: 1,
       class: 15,
       serverName: 'localhost\\SQLEXPRESS',
       procName: '' } ] }`

Comment: Give me a minute, I messed up with code formatting!

Comment: Thank you for reply. I tried running updated code , now syntax error is not there , but it is showing this message : **RequestError: A MERGE statement must be terminated by a semi-colon (;).]**

Comment: Just add `;` in the end of query (I add this to answer)

Comment: thank you very much.. Now the code is running properly.